# How to validate Azure B2C access token using Authorization in .Core application

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, authorization, azure-ad-b2c

I'm able to successfully validate an access token issued by Azure AD B2C inside the controller using this code:

```
string discoveryEndpoint = "https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyId>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new(discoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdconfig = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new()
{
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = <ClientId>,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = openIdconfig.Issuer,
    IssuerSigningKeys = openIdconfig.SigningKeys,
    ValidateLifetime = true
};
JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new();
tokenHandler.ValidateToken(accessToken, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
```

But can't make it work setting up authorization in Startup.cs like this

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
   {
       <...the same code as above to get issuer and signing keys...>
       cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new()
       {
          ValidateAudience = true,
          ValidAudience = <ClientId>,
          ValidateIssuer = true,
          ValidIssuer = openIdconfig.Issuer,
          IssuerSigningKeys = openIdconfig.SigningKeys,
          ValidateLifetime = true
       };
   });
<...>
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder)
{
   <...>
   appBuilder.UseRouting();
   appBuilder.UseAuthorization();
   <...>
}
```

and using [Authorize] attribute in my controller method. In this case I get 401 response. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

I will give you a tip.
Register events in AddJwtBearer options

```
           .AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", opts =>
           {
               opts.Authority = GetAuthority(configuration);
               opts.Audience = configuration["Authentication:AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
               opts.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
               {
                   ValidateIssuer = true,
                   ValidIssuer = configuration["Authentication:AzureAdB2C:Issuer"],
                   ValidAudiences = new string[] { opts.Audience },
                   ValidateLifetime = true,
                   NameClaimType = "name",
               };

               opts.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();

               opts.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = authFailedContext =>
               {
                   return Task.CompletedTask;
               };
               opts.Events.OnMessageReceived = messageContext =>
               {
                   return Task.CompletedTask;
               };
               opts.Events.OnTokenValidated = tokenValidatedContext =>
               {
                   return Task.CompletedTask;
               };
               opts.Events.OnForbidden = forbiddenContext =>
               {
                   return Task.CompletedTask;
               };
           });
```

and check/log azure validation context.